# How to use bootstrap standard icons in free jqgrid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

How to use icons included with Twitter Bootstrap (Glyphicon Halflings set) in jqgrid?

jqgrid allows to use FontAwesome icons but this requires including additional file.
Since bootstrap has already icons included (http://getbootstrap.com/components/) additional file causes duplication and is not nessecary.

How to use default bootstrap icons in jqgrid ?

**Update**

i'm looking for a way to replace all FontAwesome icons so that adding FontAwesome and jquery ui picture image are not more required.

Demo

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons2-fa4.htm

Shows basic icons which needs to be replaced.

New icons from top:

- Add - glyphicon-plus
- Edit -  glyphicon-pencil

etc.

Usually FontAwecome and Glyphicons have same name. Correspondence table is in

http://tagliala.github.io/vectoriconsroundup/

The other possibility is to use CSS to create icons. In this case special icon font in not needed at all.

Comment: add those boostrap classes using javascript

Comment: free jqgrid has IconSet property. `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` allows to use Font Awesome Icons without adding any code. Maybe there is a way to define bootstap standard icons in this set instead on requiting to add another font which duplicates bootstrap font? If now which javascript commands to use for replace ?

Comment: i use below for setting delete icon using bootstrap 2. Not use if it is going work for u $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
            $('.ui-icon-trash').removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-trash').addClass('btn btn-mini btn-danger icon-trash bigger-120');
        });

Comment: which icons you what replace exactly? It's more as 40 icons which can be replaced. Which one exactly you want to replace on another on (on which exactly)?

Comment: @Oleg : i'm looking for a way to use vector icons without including Font Awesome. I updated question and added comparison table

Comment: OK I will post later an example which shows how to create custom iconSet with the Add and Edit icons from glyphicon.

Comment: Currently using jqgrid with vector icons with bootstrap requires including 3 (!) icon sets: FontAweSome, Glyphicons and jquery ui icons . This is huge bloat. I'm looking for a way to reduce this bloat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) how to create `custom iconSet`

I prepared [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons2-fa4-glyphicon.htm) which demonstrates creating of custom iconSet with mix icons: the part from Font Awesome and the part from Twitter Bootstrap ([Glyphicon Halflings set](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)). It displays the results like on the picture below

[image]

where Add, Edit and some other icons (but not View icon) are from Glyphicon:

[image]

I used the following code where I moved the usage of `fa` class from top `common` property to the child place. Because I needed to use mixed icons in navigator bar. I defined empty `nav.common` and moved `fa` class in every individual icon definition. To the most important part of the code is the following

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.icons, {
    glyphIcon: {
        //common: "",
        pager: {
            common: "fa fa-fw",
            first: "fa-step-backward",
            prev: "fa-backward",
            next: "fa-forward",
            last: "fa-step-forward"
        },
        ...
        nav: {
            common: "",
            edit: "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil",
            add: "glyphicon glyphicon-plus",
            del: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash",
            search: "glyphicon glyphicon-search",
            refresh: "glyphicon glyphicon-refresh",
            view: "fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-file-o",
            save: "glyphicon glyphicon-save",
            cancel: "glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle",
            newbutton: "fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-external-link"
        },
        ...
    }
});

$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    iconSet: "glyphIcon",
    ...
});
```

I recommend you to compare the definition of icon set `glyphIcon` with the definition of icon sets `jQueryUI` and `fontAwesome` included in free jqGrid by default (see [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.0/js/grid.base.js#L259-L397)).

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! If you would create more full `iconSet` which uses `glyphicon` only you can share it with other users. You can append the information in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) or to write one more new page. The wiki of free jqGrid is opened currently for everybody for writing.