# Displaying bootstrap icon along with jqgrid caption text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I am trying to display twitter bootstrap icon in the jqgrid caption section but, the icon is not displaying. Here is the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/31/

Code Tried:

```
jQuery("#sg1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoencode: true,
    height: 'auto',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollrows: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    caption: "<i class'glyphicon glyphicon-alert'></i> Pending"
});
```

Current Output:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Am I missing anything? Is it possible to display bootstrap icon in jqgrid caption? Please suggest.

Comment: try adding $('.ui-jqgrid-title').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-alert');

Comment: @Sushil, it did not work.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/32/

Comment: even the horizontal toolbar in the demo shows that **one have more CSS compatibility problems with jqGrid 4.6 and Bootstrap**. I recommend you to try [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which supports Font Awesome (see [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8)) and in general the flexible dataset of icons. For example one can use pure bootstrap icons Glyphicon (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29285630/315935)) if you don't want to use Font Awesome icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo.  You are missing the `=` :

```
 caption: "<i class'glyphicon glyphicon-alert'></i> Pending"
```

should be:

```
 caption: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-alert'></i> Pending"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/33/

Comment: Good catch. I don't know how I missed it. But still the icon is not displaying.

Comment: Do you not see the icon in the jsfiddle?  It shows up for me.